# git : update current development branch with latest changes from master error

Tags: git, visual-studio

I did some searching on here on how to best update a current branch with the latest changes from master.

So I did this:

```
git checkout add_game_monsters && git rebase master
```

After doing this, I think my branch is in limbo because I got this error:

Patch failed at 0001 added game characters
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

So I looked at that patch file and it's like 8000 lines long.

I also can no longer change branches in Visual Studio because they are all grayed out.

I tried restarting but run into the same issue.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

A git status shows:

```
rebase in progress; onto 3cb516c3
You are currently rebasing branch 'add_game_monsters' on '3cb516c3'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")


Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by them: ../Database/Tables/dbo.gamers.sql
        deleted by them: ../Database/Tables/dbo.monsters.sql
```

Comment: Sounds like there was a conflict while rebasing. What is the output of `git status`? Add it to the question.

Comment: @eftshift0 ok done...thanks!

Comment: Well... what that tells us is that you modified 2 files that were _deleted_ on the main branch..... and so you have a tree conflict.

Comment: Oh I see...so I can just delete those and try again?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this conflict *might* require more than meets the eye. Like the changes that were made on the base branch (I know they were made on the base branch because they were *deleted* on `add_game_monsters`, which is *them* during a rebase) need to be moved to another file? But if they can be discarded just like that, you can just do:

```
git rm ../Database/Tables/dbo.gamers.sql
git rm ../Database/Tables/dbo.monsters.sql
git rebase --continue
```